# On exception during type casting add an entry to another table. Postgres (PL/pgSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

For the source table called `some_table` with the following structure & data:

```
rownumber (numeric)  |  some_column (text)
------------------------------------------
 41                  |  12/03/2016
 42                  |  invalid-text-here
 43                  |  24/04/2016
```

The following function is used to convert text containing date values into timestamp, it returns a `null` when the conversion fails.

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_to_date (scolumn anyelement, format text) RETURNS timestamp AS $$
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            RETURN cast(to_timestamp(scolumn, format) as timestamp  without time zone);
        exception when others then
            RETURN null;
        END;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It is used like this-

```
SELECT convert_to_date(some_column, 'DD/MM/YYYY') from some_table;
```

This works great.
But I now want to keep a record of all the values for which the conversion failed (**invalid-text-here** in the above table) into another table i.e.: whenever an exception occurs. So within the exception block, it should do something like this:

```
exception when others then
    INSERT INTO another_table(column_name, row_number, errval) VALUES (scolumn, rownumber, errval)
    RETURN null;
END;
```

---

How do I get the `rownumber` and `errval`?

For example, for 2nd row the `rownumber` should be **42** and `errval` should be **'invalid-text-here'**.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your Function like as given:

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_to_date (scolumn anyelement,rownumber numeric, format text) RETURNS timestamp AS $$
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            RETURN cast(to_timestamp(scolumn, format) as timestamp  without time zone);
        exception when others then
INSERT INTO another_table(column_name, row_number, errval) VALUES (scolumn, rownumber, 'invalid-text-here')
            RETURN null;
        END;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

calling will be like

```
SELECT convert_to_date(some_column,row_number, 'DD/MM/YYYY') from some_table;
```

Hope it helps.